# How to align things in my top header using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this top header, but I find it difficult to make the text at the right side of the header to stay inline with the text on the left.

This is my CSS:

```
.header-top-right {

    position: relative;

    width: 100%;

    padding-right: 15px;

    padding-left: 15px;

}

::after, ::before {

    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.header-top-right ul {

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;

    justify-content: flex-end;

}

dl, ol, ul {

    margin-top: 0;

    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    margin: 0px;

    padding: 0px;

}

ul {

    margin: 0px;

    padding: 0px;

}

.header-top-right ul li:last-child {

    margin-right: 0;

    padding-right: 0;

}

.header-top-right ul li {

    font-size: 12px;

    padding-right: 20px;

    margin-right: 20px;

    position: relative;

}

li {

    list-style: none;

}

.header-top-right ul li a {

    color: #656565;

}

a, button {

    color: #1696e7;

    outline: medium none;

}

a, .button {

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

}

a {

    color: #007bff;

    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: transparent;

}

.header-style-two 

.header-top-right ul li i {

    font-size: 14px;

    color: #a4a4a4;

}

.header-top-right ul li i {

    margin-right: 7px;

}

.header-top-right ul li i, 

.header-top-right ul li a:hover  {

    color: #0163d2;

}

.header-style-two .header-top-right ul li span {

    margin: 0 5px;

}

.header-top-right ul li a {

    color: #656565;

}

.header-style-two .header-top-area {

    background: #fbfbfb;

    padding: 14px 0;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;

}

.header-top-area {

    background: #eeeeee;

    padding: 14px 0;

}

.custom-container-two {

    max-width: 1428px;

    width: 100%;

    padding-right: 15px;

    padding-left: 15px;

    margin-right: auto;

    margin-left: auto;

}

.row {

    display: -ms-flexbox;

    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-wrap: wrap;

    margin-right: -15px;

    margin-left: -15px;

}

.header-top-left {

    position: relative;

    width: 100%;

    padding-right: 15px;

    padding-left: 15px;

}

.header-top-left ul {

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;

}

.header-top-left ul li {

    display: block;

    position: relative;

    font-size: 12px;

    color: #656565;

    padding-right: 15px;

    margin-right: 15px;

}

.header-top-left ul > li > div {

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;

}

.dropdown, .dropleft, .dropright, .dropup {

    position: relative;

}

.header-top-left .dropdown button {

    border: none;

    background: transparent;

    font-size: 12px;

    color: #656565;

    font-weight: 400;

    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

}

[type=button]:not(:disabled), [type=reset]:not(:disabled), [type=submit]:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled) {

    cursor: pointer;

}

.dropdown-toggle {

    white-space: nowrap;

}

[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {

    -webkit-appearance: button;

}

button, select {

    text-transform: none;

}

button, input {

    overflow: visible;

}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {

    margin: 0;

    font-family: inherit;

    font-size: inherit;

    line-height: inherit;

}

button {

    border-radius: 0;

}

.header-top-left .dropdown img {

    margin-right: 8px;

}

img {

    vertical-align: middle;

    border-style: none;

}

.dropdown-toggle::after {

    display: inline-block;

    margin-left: 0.255em;

    vertical-align: 0.255em;

    content: "";

    border-top: 0.3em solid;

    border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 0;

    border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;

}

.dropdown-menu {

    position: absolute;

    top: 100%;

    left: 0;

    z-index: 1000;

    display: none;

    float: left;

    min-width: 10rem;

    padding: 0.5rem 0;

    margin: 0.125rem 0 0;

    font-size: 1rem;

    color: #212529;

    text-align: left;

    list-style: none;

    background-color: #fff;

    background-clip: padding-box;

    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);

    border-radius: 0.25rem;

}

.header-top-left .dropdown .dropdown-item {

    color: #6f6f6f;

    font-size: 12px;

}

.dropdown-item {

    display: block;

    width: 100%;

    padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;

    clear: both;

    font-weight: 400;

    color: #212529;

    text-align: inherit;

    white-space: nowrap;

    background-color: transparent;

    border: 0;

}

.header-top-left ul li::after, .header-top-right ul li::after {

    content: "|";

    display: inline-block;

    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;

    transform: translateY(-50%);

    right: 0;

    color: #bcbcbc;

}

.header-top-left ul li:last-child {

    margin-right: 0;

    padding-right: 0;

}

header {

    display:block;

}
```

This is what I want:

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
         <header class="header-style-two">

        <!-- header-top -->

        <div class="header-top-area">

            <div class="custom-container-two">

                <div class="row">

                        <div class="header-top-left">

                            <ul>

                                <li>

                                    <div class="ship-to">

                                        <span>Ship to</span>

                                        <div class="dropdown">

                                            <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                                <img src="ico/ship_flag.png" alt=""> US/USD

                                            </button>

                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="ico/australia.png" alt="">AUS/USD</a>

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="ico/bng.png" alt="">BNG/TK</a>

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="ico/india.png" alt="">IN/RP</a>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <div class="header-top-guide">

                                        <span>Quick Guide</span>

                                        <div class="dropdown">

                                            <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                                Help

                                            </button>

                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="terms-conditions.html">Returns</a>

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="terms-conditions.html">Privacy</a>

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="terms-conditions.html">Terms</a>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <div class="header-top-guide">

                                        <div class="dropdown">

                                            <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                                Sell With Us

                                            </button>

                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">

                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="my-account.html">Seller Login</a>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                        <div class="header-top-right">

                            <ul>

                                <li>

                                    <a href="my-account.html"><i class="ri-user-line"></i>Register</a>

                                    <span>or</span>

                                    <a href="my-account.html">Sign in</a>

                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the code and run snippet on full page I modified code to make it more user intreactive (Sorry for modifications).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&display=swap');

*{
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}
body{
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    
  }
header {
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: auto;    
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
  &.primary-navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;

    ul {
      display: flex;
      padding-inline-start: 20px;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

    ul li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-right: 2px solid #3ca0e7;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 20px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: arvo;

    }

    li a {
      color: black;
    }

    li a:hover {
      color: #3ca0e7;
    }

    li:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul li ul {
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: none;
      background: white;
    }

    ul li:hover > ul,
    ul li ul:hover {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      min-width: 150px;
      text-align: left;
      padding-top: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px #ccc;
    }

    ul li ul li {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-style: none;
    }

    ul li ul li a:hover {
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-left: 2px solid #3ca0e7;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
  }
}

a {

    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
        color: #3CA0E7;
    }
 
}

 ul li ul li a { transition: all 0.5s ease; }

.header-right {
  display: flex ;
  padding-right: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 16px;
}

.header-right p{
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="q5.css" />
    <title>E-Commerce NavBar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">

          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

          <nav role="navigation" class="primary-navigation">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Ship to &dtrif;</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">US/USD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">AUS/USD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">BNG/TK</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">IN/RP</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Quick Guide</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help &dtrif;</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sell with us &dtrif;</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Seller Login</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="header-right">
            <p><a>Register</a></p>
            <p>or</p>
            <p><a>Sign In</a></p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```